# Can tar discover the archive format when piping it in via wget?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, gnu

When I have a tar archive of any format, I can use:

```
tar xf archive.tar.xz
tar xf anotherarchive.tar.gz
```

as tar discovers the relevant format by itself.

Now I want to download the archives and extract them without them being saved on the file system using `wget`:

```
wget -qO- http://someserver.org/sometar.tar.xz | tar xf -C ~/extractTarget
tar: -C: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I realized that the `f` flag was causing trouble as it expects the actual file. Omitting it, now lets tar complain for the relevant flag.

In case of the `gz`:

```
tar: Archive is compressed. Use -z option
```

and in case of the `xz`:

```
tar: Archive is compressed. Use -J option
```

Adding them makes my command work. Yet since tar is recognizing the archive format, I wonder:

Is there a way for it to extract them without adding the flag just like `xf`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tar xf -`. The `-` is a placeholder for standard input.

Comment: I still get: `tar: Archive is compressed. Use -J option
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` when running `wget -qO- http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.2.tar.xz | tar xf -`

Comment: If the data is compressed you would of course have to add the respective uncompress-flags in your `tar` call (like `tar xzf -`). If you want some specific decompression that `tar` does not support you can pipe the output through the decompression first before forwarding it through another pipe to `tar`.

Comment: The point of the question was that `tar xf` does not need any uncompress flag, and I want to achive the exact same thing when piping an archive in from wget.

Comment: @k0pernikus actually, `tar` does need to be passed uncompress flags, and indeed the specific uncompress flag that is needed. I suppose it could infer it from the extension in theory, but that is not done in practice. So I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @FaheemMitha New tar does not need uncompress flag. See http://askubuntu.com/a/107976/32792 for reference. And as I pointed out in my question: tar with `tar xf myarchive.tar.gz`. Or `tar xf someotherarchive.tar.xz` works. Piping them it in from wget is what causes trouble.

Comment: k0pernikus, I cannot reproduce what you say. If I try your sample `*.xz` file it won't be recognized without decompression flag whether it's first stored locally or accessed through a pipe. Though in your original question you used a `*.gz` file in one case and a `*.xz` file later, so there may (or not) be a difference here.

Comment: One more information: I read the tar command has a `-a` option which automatically detects the compression from the **file suffix**. If this is enabled in tar by default it would explain why it cannot detect the compression, since there's no file suffix if data is read from pipe.

Comment: @k0pernikus What Janis said. File based suffix detection isn't going to work for a stream from a pipe.